# yui css reset is causing my image background to get cutoff

Tags: css, yui

I'm not sure what I have to set myself to override whatever the yui css reset is doing, but here is how I add my bg:

```
body{background:#ffffff url('../assets/images/background/bg.jpg') no-repeat center top; font-family:HelveticaNeue,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; width:100%; height:100%; margin:0px; padding:0px;}
```

The problem is that my bg image stops at a certain point on my page, and I don't think it has anything to do with the amount of content in the body. Of course, when I remove the reset it looks fine.

I haven't done anything to the 'html' tag, but maybe I should?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should add this

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```